# Socket.io duplicate emit on second window

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, vue.js

I'm testing socket.io and do a simple chat message (following the tutorial in the official website)

I opened 2 windows:

When I emit the event in the first window opened, its ok.

**But, when I emit the event in second window this send the event 2 times(duplicated).**

PS: if I open a third window, this send the event 3 times

Node.js code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

 res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

 io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('chatMessage', function(msg){
  io.emit('chatMessage', msg);
  });
 });
});
```

Client side:

```
methods: {
  sendMessage: function () {
  socket.emit('chatMessage', this.text);
}


socket.on('chatMessage', function(msg){
 console.log('Client side message: ' + msg)
 vmIndex.messages.push(msg);
});
```

Comment: It's because you're creating a connection listener every time someone visits the `'/'` route. Try moving the socket-io code outside of the `'/'` route function.

Comment: thanks. is it!! add the answer ill upvote and mark as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're creating a connection listener every time someone visits the `'/'` route. Try moving the socket-io code outside of the `'/'` route function.

Answer (score 1):

As Eric mentioned, move your connection listener outside of the `/` route in order to prevent it from getting created every time someone visits the page.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('chatMessage', function(msg){
    io.emit('chatMessage', msg);
  });
});
```